# Tab Bar implementation within single view application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

I've searched for a suffice answer to this question but I've been unable to come across one that fits my dilemma. How do I implement a tab bar within my already single view application? My storyboard consist of four view controllers, a navigation view as the initial view, and 3 following table views. Now i know the order of containment must have the tab bar controller first so i embedded my navigation controller with a tab bar controller. doing this has given every view controller on my storyboard a dark gray tab bar silhouette on the bottom of each view, so i have no way of manually editing and selecting my tab bar views.

My goal is to assign my third table view controller in my storyboard as the first tab bar item. how should i do this programmatically? the first view controller acts as the default for the tab bar item. how do i change this programmatically?

here is screenshot of my storyboard:

https://41.media.tumblr.com/c3146efea93d2aeeccdcc55a6104674d/tumblr_nqqlieVI8f1tupbydo1_1280.png

here is the documentation provided by apple on the correct coding to properly assign and configure your views but its very depreciated:

https://40.media.tumblr.com/172a516075baed44cde104abf50d91aa/tumblr_nqqmngJLoA1tupbydo1_1280.png

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard? Any relevant code? I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if it's changing the order of your tab bar View Controllers, `UITabbarController` has a property called `viewControllers` which it has a strong reference to. "The order of the view controllers in the array corresponds to the display order in the tab bar. Thus, the controller at index 0 corresponds to the left-most tab, the controller at index 1 the next tab to the right, and so on." - Apple docs

Comment: just updated answer with screenshot , and there is no code yet. within my story board i embedded my navigation controller with a tab controller. and yes i understand the property's of UITabbarController, my question is, should i create a new file subclass of UITabbarController, link it to the controller in my storyboard and write my code for the controller on my storyboard there? will i be able to control everything there? @BenGabay

Comment: Yes, you will have full control of the `TabbarController`s functionality within your subclass.

Comment: check the update in my answer for the coding giving by the apple docs for assigning and configuring your content views. ONE its very depreciated and TWO its referring to the app delegate. I created a subclass file to control everything within my tab bar controller so i wouldn't need to code in the delegate. So can you in an answer give me a swift pseudo code that i can write within my subclass file that will assist me in assign my content views? @BenGabay